# Why are optimal strategies in a two-player zero-sum game convex?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

The professor told us today, that the set of optimal strategies of the row and column player in a two-player zero-sum game is convex, but he doesn't mention why that is.

What does it even mean that a set of strategies is convex?

Can somebody hint at me?

Edit: This basically means, I have to show that for any two optimal strategies a, b and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$:

$$\lambda a + (1 - \lambda)b$$

is also an optimal strategy.

Comment: It would help to provide more context of what you have learnt thus far.  A statement such as "the set of optimal strategies...is convex" clearly requires some setup (before even getting to a proof), including definitions for "strategy" and "optimal." A set is convex when any convex combination of any two elements in the set is itself an element in the set.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio We proved von Neumann's Minimax theorem using Linear programming. From what I understand is that the set of Nash equilibria is a convex set because the (feasible) set of solutions in Linear Programming is convex thus the set of NEs is also convex. But does this help me with the set of optimal strategies?